# Excel VBA - Adding 'If 0 in First Row' To Existing Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA Macro -

```
Sub CopyData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim CRow As Integer
Dim CColBRange As String
Dim PColBRange As String
Dim Continue As Boolean

'Select Sheet1
With Sheets("KG9New")
    .Select

'Initialize variables
Continue = True
CRow = 1

While Continue = True

CRow = CRow + 1

'Test B2:
 If CRow = 2 And Cells(CRow, 2).Value = 0 Then
  Range("A" & CStr(CRow) & ":C" & CStr(CRow)).Copy
     Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  CRow = CRow + 1
End If

CColBRange = "B" & CStr(CRow)
PColBRange = "B" & CStr(CRow - 1)

  'Break loop upon finding blank cell.
  If Len(Range(CColBRange).Value) = 0 Then
     Continue = False
  End If

  'Copy first instance of each changing Value in MachineRunning.
  If Range(CColBRange).Value <> Range(PColBRange).Value Then
     Range("A" & CStr(CRow) & ":C" & CStr(CRow)).Copy
     Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  End If

Wend

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Basically, This scans through Column B of my table and copies values across to a new sheet when the value changes from a 1 to a 0 or 0 to 1.

My issue is that this assumes that the first value (in B2) will be a 1.  I would like it to return Row 2 values if B2=0.

I tried changing the initialized CRow to 1, but this returns row 2 whether it is a 1 or 2 (due to it being different from the header, I guess).

Could somebody help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `CRow` to 1, like you thought. You can't test `B2` if you are never at that cell. Then you just need to do an `IF` statement.

```
Sub CopyData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim CRow As Integer
    Dim CColBRange As String
    Dim PColBRange As String
    Dim Continue As Boolean

    'Select Sheet1
    Sheets("KG9New").Select

    'Initialize variables
    Continue = True
    CRow = 1

    While Continue = True

        CRow = CRow + 1

        'Test B2:
        If CRow=2 and Cells(CRow, 2).value = 0 Then
            CRow = 3
        End if

        CColBRange = "B" & CStr(CRow)
        PColBRange = "B" & CStr(CRow - 1)


        'Break loop upon finding blank cell.
        If Len(Range(CColBRange).Value) = 0 Then
         Continue = False
        End If

        'Copy first instance of each changing Value in MachineRunning.
        If Range(CColBRange).Value <> Range(PColBRange).Value Then
         Range("A" & CStr(CRow) & ":C" & CStr(CRow)).Copy
         Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If

    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The additional `If` statement just tests to see if we are on row 2 and if that value is 0. If it is, then change `CRow` to `3` and it will continue on.

I also removed the superfluous `With` block. I couldn't see anywhere else in the Macro where that format was being used.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill.  That's exactly the help I needed.  Added your code to my original question with slight changes to suit my needs.